# How to Render the categories in database on SQL server in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, session

i am trying to show the categories in my database on `SQL` on the homepage of my **`MVC web`** , how to do that?
I have this in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
                </div>
```

this is my `Views/store/index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Store";
}
<h3>Browse Categories</h3>
<p>
    Select from @Model.Count()
    Categories:
</p>
<ul>
    @foreach (var Category in Model)
    {

        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

this is my `StoreController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

namespace MVCOnlineShop.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        OnlineStoreEntities storeDB = new OnlineStoreEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();
            return View(Categories);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Browse
        public ActionResult Browse(string Category)
        {
            // Retrieve Category and its Associated Products from database
            var CategoryModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Products")
                .Single(g => g.CategoryName == Category);

            return View(CategoryModel);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Details
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var Product = storeDB.Products.Find(id);

            return View(Product);
        }
        //
        // GET: /Store/Browse?Category=Games

    }
}
```

and this is my `Global.asax`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MVCOnlineShop
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {


            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to show categories list on home page, is this correct?

Comment: Doesn't your store/index show accurate links ?

Comment: yeah @MukeshKumar

Comment: store/index works fine ,but now i want to show categories on home page , and not in store, but in my _layout.cshtml , because i am using a bootstrap @Rafalon

Comment: You could call an instance of `OnlineStoreEntities` in your _layout.cshtml and then display whatever you want from there, but I don't know if it is good practice.

Comment: is there any other solution? @Rafalon

Comment: You can also fill a Session variable in the `Session_Start`method of your Global.asax with the data you need, and access it from your _layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do what you want to do is using Session var.

In your **Global.asax.cs** :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }

    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        // 'using' will call entity.Dispose() at the end of the block so you
        // don't have to bother about disposing your entity
        using(OnlineStoreEntities entity = new OnlineStoreEntities()){
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if(context != null && context.Session != null)
                // fill the Session var with the Categories from your database
                context.Session["Categories"] = entity.Categories.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

In your **_layout.cshtml** :

```
@using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

@*[anything you want here]*@

@{
    // stores the Session content in a var
    var Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>;
}

@*Checks if the Session variable is correct*@
@if(Categories != null){
    <ul>
        @*For each category in the Session var, display the link*@
        @foreach(var Category in Categories){
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

---

### A bit of explanation :

A Session variable is a variable accessible from anywhere on your application until it expires.

A Session variable's default duration is 20 minutes wich means if you browse your app, and stay inactive for 20 minutes, all Session vars will be lost. This duration can be configured.

The `Session_Start` method in your **Global.asax** is called once, when you first access the app, and after the Session state is declared/available. I believe this is the first place where you can set Session variables, so this is why we fill it with the data you need, at the index "Categories".

```
Session["Categories"] = entity.Categories.ToList();
```

As Session variables are accessible from anywhere in your app, we then access it in your **_layout.cshtml** so we can display every `Category` from the list.

Session variables can store any `Object` so we need to explicitly cast the value when we manipulate it.

```
List<Category> Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>;
```

Then we check if the cast succeeded with `if(Categories != null)`.

It works ? Then we can iterate over this list :

```
@foreach(Category category in Categories){}
```

Comment: @Ahmad Insert the `Session_Start` method inside the `MvcApplication` class under the `Application_Start` method.

Comment: @Ahmed Edited my answer to match your **Global.asax**. Do you mind deleting your previous comments so we don't have to move this to chat ?

Comment: ohhh niceeeeee , thankssss @Rafalon , it worked :D, you took so much effort to help me , really thanks , appreciated

Comment: but just wanted to ask you , what really happened  so it is now working , a small summary please , because i need to understand this and what happened @Rafalon

Comment: @Ahmad I think you misplaced the method, or placed the body of the method inside the `Application_Start`. The `Application_Start` method is called before the Session state is available, so this is why it didn't work.

Comment: yes you are right , really thanks!! @Rafalon , but please can you give me a small summary about what happened? , because i really need to understand this, sorry for annoying you

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do like following.

Create a CategoriesController and add following lines of codes which get your categories from database or somewhere else.

Create a class as following for category

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public string CategoryName {get;set;}
}
```

You can use following way to bind dummy data.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BlogCategories()
{
    List<CategoryViewModel> model= new List<CategoryViewModel>();
    model.Add(new CategoryViewModel(){CategoryId=1,CategoryName="AA"});
    model.Add(new CategoryViewModel(){CategoryId=2,CategoryName="BB"});
    model.Add(new CategoryViewModel(){CategoryId=3,CategoryName="CC"});
    model.Add(new CategoryViewModel(){CategoryId=4,CategoryName="DD"});
    return PartialView("BlogCategories",model);
}
```

and create a partial view as following which show your categories data.

```
@model List<DotnetTutorial.Data.ViewModel.CategoryViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
       <div class="categoryLi">
            @Html.RouteLink(item.CategoryName, "ArticlesCategoryList")
        </div>        
}
```

and at the last, you can just call this partial view on your home page using following line of code.

```
@Html.Action("BlogCategories", "Categories")
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: _categoryRepository.GetCategoryList();
This is instance of my category repository class, instead of this you can you any other ways to get data.

Comment: made simple example for you.

Comment: I really think the OP wants the links to be displayed everywhere on the app, so inside the **_layout.cshtml**. Your example will allow him to display the links only on the "BlogCategories" view of some Controller.